# Hay una opción para desactivar el autoseleccionado del button en form?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Intento hacer un:

```
private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Escape)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Para cerrar el formulario al darle esc, pero tengo un GroupBox con unos botones en el form y no me lo hace, no sé cómo desactivar o si hay una opción que te permite deseleccionar el botón y poder darle al esc o space o cualquier tecla sin interactuar con el botón.

Comment: En Microsoft Forms, ve al formulario para el que deseas editar la configuración y, desde ahí, selecciona Más configuraciones de formulario > Configuración. En el Configuración, puede seleccionar o borrar opciones. Nota: La opción para la configuración del cuestionario solo está disponible para cuestionarios.

Answer (score 2):

El formulario tiene una propiedad que se llama **keypreview**, ponla a **true** a través del **object inspector**, esta propiedad lo que hace es capturar cualquier tecla que se pulse antes de que el control que tiene el foco la reciba, es decir primero es detectada por el formulario, pruébalo y me dices.

Answer (score 1):

Usa el metodo `stopPropagation` del objeto `event` de Javascript.

```
private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Escape)
    {
        e.stopPropagation();
        this.Close();

    }
}
```

Este método evita que se ejecuten todas las demás acciones que estén pendientes de ejecutarse para ese evento.

Javascript asigna escuchadores (listeners) a los eventos, en tu caso la función `Form1_KeyPress` sería la función asociada a un listener (handler) del evento `keypress` en el formulario, esos escuchadores son guardados en una cola y cuando se dispara el evento se van ejecutando de forma secuencual 1 a 1 hasta completarlos todos. Si quieres parar esa ejecución en cadena en algún listener, solo tienes que invocar a la función `stopPropagation()` sobre el objeto `event` que llega a tu función (Javascript se encarga de enviar este objeto a tu función asociada al listener)

[Ejemplo de uso](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Examples#Example_5:_Event_Propagation)

Comment: no es javascript, es c#

Comment: @Wail, no importa is es c# o no. Lo importante es que es Windows Forms, y no Web Forms, ASP.NET MVC u otra aplicación web

Answer (score 1):

Habilita el keypreview en el formulario, lo que habilita la captura de las teclas presionadas durante la ejecucion del programa y se mantenga el foco en la ventana.